# Substituting same value multiple times with nginx sub_filter

Tags: nginx

**Edit:** Reproducible example: https://github.com/searchingforlife/nginx-substitution

I am trying to add/inject arbitrary number of scripts to an HTML file/output. They all filter on the same value `</body>` to inject themselves.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
```

Imagine we have two conf files like so (simplified):

```
# script_one.conf

sub_filter "</body>" "<script src='/one.js'></script></body>";
```

```
# script_two.conf

sub_filter "</body>" "<script src='/two.js'></script></body>";
```

And our main nginx conf file:

```
location /one {
  sub_filter_once off;
  include /script_one.conf;
  include /script_two.conf;
}
```

This however does not seem to work and nginx only adds the first script. If the filter value is different (say one filters on `</head>` and the other on `</body>`), then nginx injects both scripts.

Is there a way to get around this limitation and have nginx inject both scripts? I know I can create a new conf file that combines both scripts into one and include that but that just doesn't scale when you have 10+ scripts to inject that can be combined in various ways depending on the location.

Comment: As shown, it should work. Something else is probably going on. Please post the output of  `nginx -T`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Added repo to reproduce this behavior: https://github.com/searchingforlife/nginx-substitution

Comment: try using `"></body>"` on the second `sub_filter`. you already know what's on your previous `sub_filter`, so try avoid identical matches on it on your next `sub_filter`, though IMO, you can just inject one script, and dynamically load other scripts from said script, e.g. use `sub_filter` to inject a bootstrap script, and load subsequent JS files on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation, I haven't verified it from nginx source code. I assume nginx stores the keys to replace in a hash structure, that is, replace `x` with `y`.

Now, when nginx reads the configuration file in order, it first adds a key `</body>` to the replace map, and then replaces it with the second one.

Comment: You're likely right. Instead, I thought about a different approach that seems to solve this issue where we only rewrite once. If anyone is interested, see the solution branch: https://github.com/searchingforlife/nginx-substitution/tree/solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up thinking a different approach which only rewrites once. If anyone is interested, see the solution branch: https://github.com/searchingforlife/nginx-substitution/tree/solution

Basically, we create a variable that holds names of scripts to inject, and then inject them all at once. This way, we end up only rewriting once.

```
location ~ ^/ {
  set $js_args "one,two";
  include scripts.conf;
}
```

```
# scripts.conf

if ($js_args ~ "^$") {
  set $js_args '';
}

set $scripts "";

if ($js_args ~* "(,|^)one([,]|$)") {
  set $scripts "${scripts}<script src='/one.js'></script>";
}

if ($js_args ~* "(,|^)two([,]|$)") {
  set $scripts "${scripts}<script src='/two.js'></script>";
}

sub_filter "</body>" "${scripts}</body>";
```